# Is it possible to use objects in an ArrayList to set labels and radio buttons in JavaFx and Scene Builder?

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to create a multiple choice movie game where a movie appears in the label and the actor matched with that movie and 3 randoms are set as the radio buttons. Every example or tutorials I have found online show me how to use JavaFx and Scene Builder without implementing any classes or objects already written. I have a class called MovieSet that takes in an Arraylist of movies, and I do the same with the actors. However all the tutorials online never say if its possible to set the labels and radio buttons to these arraylist.

Is it possible to do this? and if so how would this be done?

I have used a for loop to iterate over the movieList, but it is telling me it cannot find symbol for movieList

```
public static void displayMovies(ArrayList<Movie> movieList) {
    for (int x = 0; x < movieList.size(); x++) {
        Movie movie = movieList.get(x);
        System.out.printf("%s", movie.toString());
    }
}
```

This is my controller. I do apologize. This is my first time using JavaFX and

```
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Label movielabel;

    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
       MovieSet movie = new MovieSet(); 
       this.movielabel.getLabelFor(MovieSet.displayMovies(movieList));
    }    

}
```

Comment: What does `MovieSet` looks like?

Answer (score 0):

This sample app is a general way of handling a multiple choice question and answer app. Comments in code.

> Main Class

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class MultipleChoiceGameExample extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception
    {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

> Controller

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable
{

    @FXML
    private Label lblQuestionNumber;
    @FXML
    private TextArea taQuestionDisplay;
    @FXML
    private Button btnAnswer1, btnAnswer2, btnAnswer3, btnAnswer4, btnNextQuestion;

    List<Question> questions;
    int currentQuestion = 0;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb)
    {
        //Get Questions from Database or what ever source you use
        FakeDatabaseHandler fakeDatabaseHandler = new FakeDatabaseHandler();
        questions = fakeDatabaseHandler.getQuestions();
        //Shuffle the questions
        Collections.shuffle(questions);
        //Load first question
        lblQuestionNumber.setText("Question 1 of " + questions.size());
        loadQuestion(questions.get(currentQuestion));
    }

    @FXML
    public void handleBtnNextQuestion(ActionEvent actionEvent)
    {
        currentQuestion++;
        if (currentQuestion < questions.size()) {
            lblQuestionNumber.setText("Question " + (currentQuestion + 1) + " of " + questions.size());
            loadQuestion(questions.get(currentQuestion));
        }
        else {
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.WARNING);
            alert.setTitle("Game Over Alert");
            alert.setContentText("There are no more questions!");
            alert.showAndWait();
        }
    }

    public void loadQuestion(Question question)
    {
        taQuestionDisplay.setText(question.getQuestion());//Set the question
        List<String> choices = question.getIncorrectAnswers();//Get the incorrect answers
        choices.add(question.getCorrectAnswer());////Get the correct answer and add it.
        Collections.shuffle(choices);//Randomize the choices

        //Add buttons to List to make creating event handlers easier
        List<Button> choicesButtons = new ArrayList();
        choicesButtons.add(btnAnswer1);
        choicesButtons.add(btnAnswer2);
        choicesButtons.add(btnAnswer3);
        choicesButtons.add(btnAnswer4);
        //Set the choices to a Button
        for (int i = 0; i < choices.size(); i++) {
            choicesButtons.get(i).setText(choices.get(i));
        }

        //Create Action handlers for each button
        for (Button button : choicesButtons) {
            button.setOnAction(actionEvent -> {
                //Check if button's text equals the correct answer
                if (button.getText().equals(question.getCorrectAnswer())) {
                    Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
                    alert.setTitle("Answer Alert");
                    alert.setHeaderText("Correct!");
                    alert.setContentText("You got the answer right!");
                    alert.showAndWait();
                }
                else {
                    Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
                    alert.setTitle("Answer Alert");
                    alert.setHeaderText("Incorrect!");
                    alert.setContentText("You got the answer wrong!\nThe correct answer is " + question.getCorrectAnswer());
                    alert.showAndWait();
                }
            });
        }

    }

}
```

> FXML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextArea?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="476.0" prefWidth="668.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.141" fx:controller="multiplechoicegameexample.FXMLDocumentController">
    <children>
        <Label fx:id="label" layoutX="126" layoutY="120" minHeight="16" minWidth="69" />
      <VBox alignment="TOP_CENTER" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
         <children>
            <Label fx:id="lblQuestionNumber" alignment="CENTER" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" text="Label" />
            <TextArea fx:id="taQuestionDisplay" prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="200.0">
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
               </VBox.margin>
            </TextArea>
            <GridPane hgap="5.0" maxWidth="400.0" vgap="5.0">
              <columnConstraints>
                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
              </columnConstraints>
              <rowConstraints>
                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
              </rowConstraints>
               <children>
                  <Button fx:id="btnAnswer1" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
                  <Button fx:id="btnAnswer2" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
                  <Button fx:id="btnAnswer3" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                  <Button fx:id="btnAnswer4" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
               </children>
            </GridPane>
              <Button fx:id="btnNextQuestion" onAction="#handleBtnNextQuestion" text="Next Question">
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets top="20.0" />
               </VBox.margin>
            </Button>
         </children>
      </VBox>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

> Question Class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class Question
{

    private String question;
    private String correctAnswer;
    private List<String> incorrectAnswers = new ArrayList();

    public Question(String question, String correctAnswer, List<String> incorrectAnswers)
    {
        this.question = question;
        this.correctAnswer = correctAnswer;
        this.incorrectAnswers = incorrectAnswers;
    }

    public String getQuestion()
    {
        return question;
    }

    public void setQuestion(String question)
    {
        this.question = question;
    }

    public String getCorrectAnswer()
    {
        return correctAnswer;
    }

    public void setCorrectAnswer(String correctAnswer)
    {
        this.correctAnswer = correctAnswer;
    }

    public List<String> getIncorrectAnswers()
    {
        return incorrectAnswers;
    }

    public void setIncorrectAnswers(List<String> incorrectAnswers)
    {
        this.incorrectAnswers = incorrectAnswers;
    }
}
```

> Database Handler(You may get your data from a different source)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class FakeDatabaseHandler
{

    List<Question> questions = new ArrayList();

    public FakeDatabaseHandler()
    {
        //connect to db!
        //Simulate getting data from db!
        List<String> incorrectAnswersQuestion1 = new ArrayList();
        incorrectAnswersQuestion1.add("Pakistan");
        incorrectAnswersQuestion1.add("Palau");
        incorrectAnswersQuestion1.add("Panama");
        questions.add(new Question("Which is the only American state to begin with the letter 'p'?", "Pennsylvania", incorrectAnswersQuestion1));
        List<String> incorrectAnswersQuestion2 = new ArrayList();
        incorrectAnswersQuestion2.add("Mississppi");
        incorrectAnswersQuestion2.add("Nile");
        incorrectAnswersQuestion2.add("Yangtze");
        questions.add(new Question("What is the world's longest river?", "Amazon", incorrectAnswersQuestion2));
        List<String> incorrectAnswersQuestion3 = new ArrayList();
        incorrectAnswersQuestion3.add("6,000 miles");
        incorrectAnswersQuestion3.add("10,000 miles");
        incorrectAnswersQuestion3.add("12,000 miles");
        questions.add(new Question("What is the diameter of Earth?", "8,000 miles", incorrectAnswersQuestion3));
    }

    public List<Question> getQuestions()
    {
        return questions;
    }

}
```

[image]