# JavaFX button pressing (Events)

Tags: java, javafx

My idea was to show a question, and you have two buttons there ( Yes, No ). When you push a "Yes" button for answering the question, code will give a feedback ("Yes, you are correct") , same with "No". This is what i have. I had someideas, for example, to somehow remove the Text and replace it with the next one. Maybe to create list with the questions, and when you answer something, code will take from the list next question.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.FontWeight;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Ulesanne6 extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Axe a question");
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        Text t0 = new Text(200, 300, "Are you human ?");
        Text t1 = new Text(200, 300, "5 + 5 = 10");
        Text t2 = new Text(200, 300, "Sun is big ?");
        Text t3 = new Text(200, 300, "Are you a car?");
        t0.setFont(Font.font("Tahoma", FontWeight.NORMAL, 20));
        t1.setFont(Font.font("Tahoma", FontWeight.NORMAL, 20));
        t2.setFont(Font.font("Tahoma", FontWeight.NORMAL, 20));
        t3.setFont(Font.font("Tahoma", FontWeight.NORMAL, 20));
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        Button btn = new Button();
        Button btn2 = new Button();

        btn.setLayoutX(200);
        btn.setLayoutY(330);

        btn2.setLayoutX(300);
        btn2.setLayoutY(330);

        btn.setText("Yes");
        btn2.setText("No");
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler <javafx.event.ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(javafx.event.ActionEvent event) {

            }
        });

        btn2.setOnAction(new EventHandler <javafx.event.ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(javafx.event.ActionEvent event) {


            }
        });

        Pane root = new Pane();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);
        root.getChildren().add(btn2);
        root.getChildren().add(t0);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 800, 600));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

I am sure, that i need to do something here). " If button is pressed... remove text, replace with another one...".

```
btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler <javafx.event.ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(javafx.event.ActionEvent event) {

            }
        });

        btn2.setOnAction(new EventHandler <javafx.event.ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(javafx.event.ActionEvent event) {


            }
        });
```

Comment: Consider using `HBox` and `VBox` or `GridPane` instead of `Pane` to automatically determine the locations of the nodes. Furthermore it would be easier to modify the nodes instead of replacing them. E.g. `t0.setText("some new Text");`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49635282/is-it-possible-to-use-objects-in-an-arraylist-to-set-labels-and-radio-buttons-in/49637768#49637768